# Reduce battery depletion when in suspend mode on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: grub2, uefi, power-management, battery, secure-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 21.10 on my new machine, dual-booting with Windows (for the time being). My setup is however not the *usual setup*; I have a `/boot` partition of 1GB on my disk and a `/` partition of 128GB setup with LUKS (by selecting "physical device for encryption" in the installer and then selecting it as the root partition).

Now, everything but the suspend mode works fine. When I enable suspend, my power usage is exactly the same as if my machine was being used, which is odd. For example, in 30 minutes time there would be a battery drop of 2%.
I checked `/sys/power/mem_sleep` to check the kernel system sleep state, which was set to `s2idle`. So, following a post somewhere else, I changed it to the `deep` (by changing the kernel args in GRUB). Now this resulted in the entire battery finishing off in less than three hours! So, I switched it back to `s2idle` which atleast has a lower battery drop.

> Point to note: The battery drop doesn't happen on Windows

I'd really appreciate any recommendations from the community! FWIW, I'm on a Dell Inspiron 16 (2021, with NVIDIA GFX; proprietary drivers installed and set to integrated graphics to save power)

**Edit**

- `uname -r`: 5.13.0-20-generic
- Display server: Wayland/Xorg (same result on both)